# Unresolved reference: Transformations

Tags: android, kotlin, transformation

I'm trying to follow the android documentation to implement Transformations in my project but I run into this problem *Unresolved reference: Transformations*. I don't know why my project can't see the Transformations class.

I'm using Kotlin version 1.5.21' and here is my code

```
class MyViewModel(private val repository: PostalCodeRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private val addressInput = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val postalCode: LiveData<String> = Transformations.switchMap(addressInput) {
            address -> repository.getPostCode(address) }


    private fun setInput(address: String) {
        addressInput.value = address
    }
}
```

Any guidance is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to import

```
import androidx.lifecycle.Transformations
```

If the import gives an `Unresolved reference` error, add the following dependency to your `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1"
}
```

Answer (score 73):

From lifecycle version 2.6.0 instead of using `Transformations`, you need to use the extension function directly `myLiveData.switchMap` or `myLiveData.map` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75465436/10322720))

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer, since downgrading to a previous version is not a good path.

Comment: How can I use switchMap or map in the same way?

Answer (score 13):

If there is a **Class of PageViewModel** like this

```
class PageViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _index = MutableLiveData<Int>()
   val text: LiveData<String> = Transformations.map(_index) {
        "$it"
   }


    fun setIndex(index: Int) {
        _index.value = index
    }
}
```

The new version can be like this:

```
class PageViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _index = MutableLiveData<Int>()

    val text: LiveData<String> = _index.map { "$it" }


    fun setIndex(index: Int) {
        _index.value = index
    }
}
```