# Unresolved reference: Transformations after upgrading lifecycle dependency

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-livedata-transformations

After upgrading the lifecycle dependency from `2.6.0-alpha04` to `2.6.0-beta01` I got Unresolved reference: Transformations and it can't `import androidx.lifecycle.Transformations` class.

```
import androidx.lifecycle.Transformations
...
var myList: LiveData<List<Bookmark>> = Transformations.switchMap(
            bookMarkType
        ) { input: Int? ->
            when (input) {
                ARTICLE_BOOKMARK -> return@switchMap repository.articleBookmarks
                WEBSITE_BOOKMARK -> return@switchMap repository.websiteBookmarks
                LINK_BOOKMARK -> return@switchMap repository.linkBookmarks
            }
            repository.websiteBookmarks
        }
```

Comment: A `var` is used here as this is mutable in another context that not needed to mention here; so just in this context here it could be `val` normally

Comment: If there is a Class of PageViewModel like this , see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76396193/12272687

Answer (score 94, accepted):

[As of 2.6.0-alpha05 version:](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.6.0-alpha05)

> Transformations is now written in Kotlin. This is a source incompatible change for those classes written in Kotlin that were directly using syntax such as Transformations.map - Kotlin code must now use the Kotlin extension method syntax that was previously only available when using lifecycle-livedata-ktx. When using the Java programming language, the versions of these methods that take an androidx.arch.core.util.Function method are deprecated and replaced with the versions that take a Kotlin Function1.

So, instead of using `Transformations`, you need to use the extension function directly `myLiveData.switchMap` or `myLiveData.map`

So, to fix this use:

```
var myList: LiveData<List<Bookmark>> = bookMarkType.switchMap { input: Int? ->
            when (input) {
                ARTICLE_BOOKMARK -> return@switchMap repository.articleBookmarks
                WEBSITE_BOOKMARK -> return@switchMap repository.websiteBookmarks
                LINK_BOOKMARK -> return@switchMap repository.linkBookmarks
            }
            repository.websiteBookmarks
        }
```

Comment: kudos mate \\(^-^)/

Comment: saved lot of time and efforts, Cheers!!!

Answer (score 5):

[Zain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9851608/zain) has given a fantastic answer, but just to elaborate and generalise for someone trying to convert one type of LiveData to another using Transformations.map() and getting "Unresolved reference..." issue.

If you have a LiveData of type 'T', and you wanted to convert it to LiveData of type 'X' using Transformations.map(), here's what you can do now(as of Lifecycle_version >= 2.6.0)

```
val oldTypeLiveData : LiveData<T> = ...

val newTypeLiveData : LiveData<X> = oldTypeLiveData.map{
...pass your lambda to provide implementation for the transformation
}
```

Here's a [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Transformations#(androidx.lifecycle.LiveData).map(kotlin.Function1)) to Android Developers

Answer (score 0):

When using the Java programming language, use `kotlin.jvm.functions`: `Function0`, `Function1`, `Function2`, `Function3`, ...

```
import androidx.lifecycle.Transformations;
import kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1;
.....
```

**and replace this**

```
 LiveData<List<TEntityRecord>> list = Transformations.switchMap(keyTime,
        new Function<Long, LiveData<List<TEntityRecord>>>() {
        ....
        });
```

**with this**

```
 LiveData<List<TEntityRecord>> list = Transformations.switchMap(keyTime,
        new Function1<Long, LiveData<List<TEntityRecord>>>() {
        ....
           @Override
           public LiveData<List<TEntityRecord>> invoke(Long mtime) {
              return repository.getList(mtime);
              }
        });
```

Comment: Transformations doesn´t exist

Comment: Be sure to have implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.6.2" 
which should allow "import androidx.lifecycle.Transformations;"

Comment: Thanks mate, I was searching this for hours, even ChatGpt could not answer it.