# Can't find Transformations in androidx.lifecycle

Tags: android, androidx, android-lifecycle, android-livedata-transformations

I've got an unresolved failure while importing androidx.lifecycle.Transformations after adding the related dependencies in the build.gradle.kts:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxPar.png).

Following are the dependencies added:

```
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.7.0")
```

How can I resolve this?

Following is the entire build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.lifecycletest"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.lifecycletest"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.7.0")
}
```

Comment: Others like `liveData` in androidx.lifecycle can be imported as `androidx.lifecycle.liveData` correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75465435/unresolved-reference-transformations-after-upgrading-lifecycle-dependency please find the similar question here